# How to connect a function declaration between Node and Jasmine files?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node

In my pigLatin Jasmine file I am trying to get the following code to work:

```
var pigLatin = require("./pigLatin.js");

describe('#translate', function() {
    it('translates a word beginning with a vowel', function() {
    s = translate("apple");
    expect(pigLatin.s).toEqual('appleay');
    });
});
```

Here is my Node file:

```
function translate(argument) {
    return "appleay";
}


module.exports = {
    translate
}
```

I think this has something to do with the spy feature but I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around what it does exactly. Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brad I was able to figure this out. Here is the fixed solution:

```
var pigLatin = require("./pigLatin.js");

describe('#translate', function() {
it('translates a word beginning with a vowel', function() {
    s = pigLatin.translate("apple");
    expect(s).toEqual('appleay');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `pigLatin.js` file only exports the function `translate`, so when you import the file, you are storing the function into the variable `pigLatin`.

So for your `describe` you'd want something more like...

```
var translate = require("./pigLatin.js");

describe('#translate', function() {
    it('translates a word beginning with a vowel', function() {
    s = translate("apple"); // we imported the translate function
    expect(s).toEqual('appleay'); // `s` is the result of the translation
    });
});
```

Whatever is exported by a module is what is returned by the `require` function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution didn't quite solve it but it did point me in the right direction. I'll post the solution as an official answer.

Comment: Oh! I see what I missed. I'm sorry! Glad you figured it out. :)